# Internal vs external database in Android app

Tags: android, database, storage

I'm starting with Android development, and I'm trying to do an application that will help users to find events around where they live.  Most of those events are static, and therefore could be stored in an internal database.  However, there are other events that might have to be added, or existing events that might have to be modified.
My questions are the following:

1. Which aspects should I take into consideration in order to decide whether should I use an internal database or external database?
2. If I decide to use an internal database, what are the approaches to update the user database with the new events or whatever changes that might have to be done?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without too much detail about your app, I'd keep an internal database that you periodically update from a remote server (which I assume you're calling the "external database").

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  At which point, or why would you prefer using a database from a remote server and make all the petitions to it?

Comment: If you only use and internal database, you can't update the data.  Not easily, anyway.  You'd need to do an app update.  "Events", even if some are static, seem like something that changes over time.  Also, "near you" is pretty specific.  I would imagine you'd want to be able to download that from a remote server.  Why I would do both, always needing a web connection is bad for usability.  When designing, I like to think of phones as mostly offline rather than on.

Answer (score 1):

To extend a bit Kevin's answer I would add that one of the approach could be to use an external database that just return through a webservice a timestamp of the last database update. If this timestamp changes, your local database should be update (maybe by sending only differential changes).

Internal database is an interesting solution if : your app means to be running without connection or the data volume is too important to be requested at each launch.